# Как в php получить потребляемую память и cpu?

Tags: php

Хочу иметь возможность написать 1-2 строки перед куском кода который хочу потестировать и в конце 1-2 строки чтобы они потом выводили потребляемую память и процессор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.memory-get-usage.php

```
memory_get_usage
```

(PHP 4 >= 4.3.2, PHP 5) `memory_get_usage` — Возвращает количество памяти выделенной PHP

#### Описание

```
int memory_get_usage ([ bool $real_usage = false ] )
```

Возвращает количество памяти в байтах, которое было выделено PHP скрипту на на данный момент.

**Список параметров**

`real_usage`. Передача `TRUE` позволяет узнать реальное количество памяти, выделенной PHP скрипту системой. Если аргумент не задан или равен `FALSE`, будет возвращено только количество памяти, выделенное с помощью функции `emalloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
memory_get_usage
```

`sys_getloadavg` немножко не то, но наиболее близкое к вашим требованиям

Пример: 
http://www.tonylea.com/2012/how-to-get-memory-and-cpu-usage-in-php/

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).